# ThreeJS animate light color

Tags: three.js

I've made a directional light that I want to change color over time. I'm reading [the documentation](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Math/Color), but still not getting it up and running. 
Before init I declare variables:

```
var rmapped = 0;
var color;
var frontLight;
```

In my init I have:

```
color = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
var frontLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(color, 1);
frontLight.position.set(0, 0, 3000);
frontLight.castShadow = true;
frontLight.shadowDarkness = 1;
frontLight.shadowMapSoft = true;
scene.add(frontLight);
```

And in my update() I have:

```
rmapped = rmapped +.1;
color.add(rmapped,1,1)
```

I'm just as happy using HSL, or using addScalar(). I just  need something up and running that can change the color every frame.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the light color via `frontLight.color`.

https://jsfiddle.net/8qaf13nv/

```
// h — hue value between 0.0 and 1.0 
// s — saturation value between 0.0 and 1.0 
// l — lightness value between 0.0 and 1.0
var h = rmapped * 0.01 % 1;
var s = 0.5;
var l = 0.5;
frontLight.color.setHSL ( h, s, l );

rmapped ++;
```